# Twitter Bootstrap tooltip on mouseenter event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

To put you in situation, this is the problem:

In my webapp I have a button that fires a Bootstrap popover and with the event 'show' of the popover makes an ajax call, p. e:

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
     //code...
});
```

Inside the function I made the ajax call, until this point everything works great, inside the popover there is a link with rel="tooltip" to make the Bootstrap tooltip. Well, I bind a mouseenter event to this element to make something like Facebook when you are hovering a Like button and appears all the people who likes the publication.

Here comes the problem, it works well but for some reason it fires again the ajax call of the popover and again the ajax call attached at the mouseenter event.

Comment: That's what it does, fires everytime you mouseover, again and again!

Comment: use conditions and data-tags to make a comparison between states.

Comment: he is not using mouseover, mouseenter is supposed to fire only once when you are inside the element http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: @Ricardo can you showcase the issue in this fiddle with minimal code http://jsfiddle.net/ucsZH/

Comment: @PSL - It still runs the ajax call everytime you move the cursor into the element, which is probably what the issue is!

Comment: @PSL the code is in your jsfiddle, check it out.

Comment: @adeneo it has no sense that the mouseenter event fires an ajax call attached to other element with a different event. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @RicardoCámara can you share the fiddle.

Comment: @PSL yes, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ucsZH/13/)

Comment: @PSL I found the solution, the problem was here:

    $('#myModal').on('show', function() {
        //code...
    });

For some reason the event 'show' is fired all the time. Now, I bind the event to the button with a click event and all works great now.